# MySQL query show times in milliseconds, not seconds?

Tags: mysql

In psql, with `\timing on`, query times are displayed in milliseconds + hundredths of milliseconds. In MySQL, they are only displayed in seconds + hundredths of seconds. Is there a way to get MySQL to display them in milliseconds too (I'm trying to compare queries, but the small times just come out as zero in MySQL, which isn't very helpful).

Comment: Try `set profiling=1;`

As suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825838/mysql-query-execution-time-can-i-get-this-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

For a test/check session you can enable the [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) and setting the sysvar `long_query_time` to 0

> The minimum and default values of long_query_time are 0 and 10,
>   respectively.  The value can be specified to a resolution of
>   microseconds.  For logging to a file, times are written including the
>   microseconds part.  For logging to tables, only integer times are
>   written; the microseconds part is ignored